# Oracle SQL - Group by one column and list results in another

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query which returns the following results...

```
SELECT wk, cost FROM my_table WHERE id = '234' order by week

WK  COST
--------
17  446
18  446
19  446
26  588
27  588
28  588
```

What I need to try and do is write a query to achieve the following results...

```
WKS           COST
------------------
17, 18, 19    446
26, 27, 28    588
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this,

```
WITH t(wk, COST) AS
(
SELECT 17,  446 FROM dual
UNION 
SELECT 18,  446 FROM dual
UNION 
SELECT 19,  446 FROM dual
UNION 
SELECT 26,  588 FROM dual
UNION 
SELECT 27,  588 FROM dual
UNION 
SELECT 28,  588 FROM dual
)
SELECT listagg(wk,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY wk) AS wks, COST 
FROM   t
GROUP BY COST;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
By using LISTAGG function you can achieve what you are trying to do.       

 SELECT deptno
        ,LISTAGG(sal, '-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sal) AS employees
           FROM   emp
            GROUP  BY
                   deptno;

    -----------------------------------------------------
    OUTPUT
    -----------------------------------------------------
    DEPTNO EMPLOYEES 
    10     1300-2450-5000 
    20     800-1100-2975-3000-3000 
    30     950-1250-1250-1500-1600-2850 

    3 rows returned in 0.01 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

If not using oralce 11g then you need to go with below solution otherwise what @Dba answered

```
  WITH t AS
     (SELECT 17 wk, 446 COST
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 18 wk, 446 COST
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 19 wk, 446 COST
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 26 wk, 588 COST
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 27 wk, 588 COST
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 28 wk, 588 COST
        FROM DUAL)
SELECT     COST,
           LTRIM
              (MAX (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (wk, ','))KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),
               ','
              ) AS COST
      FROM (SELECT wk, COST,
                   ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY COST ORDER BY wk) AS curr,
                     ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY COST ORDER BY wk)
                   - 1 AS prev
              FROM t)
  GROUP BY COST
CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND COST = PRIOR COST
START WITH curr = 1;
```